# JACKSON how to not include the wrapper for a field ? 

Tags: java, jackson

JACKSON how to not include the wrapper for a field ?

```
public  class AuthType {
    Map<String,String> properties;

    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<String, String> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

}
```

It returns

```
{"properties":{"authType":"XYZ"}}
```

but i want to have the

```
{"authType":"XYZ"}
```

Any annotation ?

Looks like there is no support for it http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-765 any workaround ?

Comment: Why don't you just do objectMappger.writeValueAsString(authType.getProperties()) ?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Jackson 1.9, you can use the [@JsonUnwrapped](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation

```
public  class AuthType {
    Map<String,String> properties;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<String, String> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class is actually that simple, use Jackson's [custom serializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers) or simply serialize it as a [tree](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `@JsonAnyGetter` to Map; and if you need to read it back, define matching `@JsonAnySetter`.